# Go/Python asynchronous bridge

Tags: python, go, asynchronous, ctypes

I wrote a client to handle lower-level TLS connection parameters like ClientHellos etc.

I did this in Go since it's a lot easier there. My main program (webscraper) is in Python. I connected the Go source to my Python file through a DLL via ctypes. My webscraper structure was asynchronous so far, to handle multiple connections at a time.

Unfortunately, my Go client is not asynchronous. Is there a way I can change it in Python so it asynchronously awaits a response from the ctypes pointer until it is there? Right now it's waiting for a response but blocks all other code executions in the meantime obviously.

EDIT:
Code example below

```
async def request(self, method, url, headers, body=None, rawBody=None, pseudoHeaderOrder=["method", "authority", "scheme", "path"]):
        global httpLib
        global initFunc
        global requestFunc
        global changeProxyFunc
        global freePointerFunc
        config = {
            "id": self.cid,
            "method": method.upper(),
            "timeout": 20000,
            "url": url,
            "pseudoHeaderOrder": pseudoHeaderOrder,
            "headers": headers
        }
        #Critical
        if body:
            config["body"] = body
        if rawBody:
            rawBody = [b for b in bytes(rawBody, "utf-8")]
            config["rawBody"] = rawBody
        config = json.dumps(config)
        #print(config)
        #THIS PART CASTS THE REQUEST
        ptr = requestFunc(config.encode('utf-8'))
        string = ctypes.cast(ptr, ctypes.c_char_p).value.decode("utf-8")
        #THIS PART CLEARS THE POINTER
        freePointerFunc(ptr)
        #...
```

Comment: Is your Python program asynchronous by means of multithreading or by using asyncio? It would help if you showed a [mre] of the part in your Python application that waits for the ctypes pointer.

Comment: Apologies @mkrieger1 - forgot to add the code since I was in quite a hurry. As seen above, I use AsyncIO for the execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the blocking call to a separate thread/process using an [executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#executing-code-in-thread-or-process-pools).

Something like this should work,

```py
async def request(self, method, url, headers, body=None, rawBody=None, pseudoHeaderOrder=["method", "authority", "scheme", "path"]):
        global httpLib
        global initFunc
        global requestFunc
        global changeProxyFunc
        global freePointerFunc
        config = {
            "id": self.cid,
            "method": method.upper(),
            "timeout": 20000,
            "url": url,
            "pseudoHeaderOrder": pseudoHeaderOrder,
            "headers": headers
        }
        #Critical
        if body:
            config["body"] = body
        if rawBody:
            rawBody = [b for b in bytes(rawBody, "utf-8")]
            config["rawBody"] = rawBody
        config = json.dumps(config)
        
        # Move blocking code to separate function
        def blocking_io():
          ptr = requestFunc(config.encode('utf-8'))
          string = ctypes.cast(ptr, ctypes.c_char_p).value.decode("utf-8")
          freePointerFunc(ptr)
          return string

        # Aschronously wait on the result
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        string = await loop.run_in_executor(None, blocking_io)
        
        #...
```